# Implementing Composite (Embedded-ID) Foreign Key Relations using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Interestingly, I can't find any solution for a seemingly common scenario! So I'm asking here to learn from experienced professionals in [Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa). I'll consider using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to make the sample codes more concise.

Consider a simple [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com) example web application. I've defined two simple entities as below:

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private int year;
    private int rating;
}

@Data
@Entity
public class Actor {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date birthday;
    private String gender;
}
```

Now we need a join-table to link these two entities; but this is not just a simple join-table. Other than the `actor` and `movie` columns, this table has some additional attributes. We didn't want to waste storage by adding an `ID` column here, instead we used a composite-key consisting of `actor` and `movie`:

```java
@Data
@Embeddable
public class MovieActorId implements Serializable {
    
    private Actor actor;
    private Movie movie;
}

@Data
@Entity
public class MovieActor {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private MovieActorId id;
    private int salary;
    private String characterName;
}
```

There are two Many-to-One relations here: `MovieActor >-- Actor` and `MovieActor >-- Movie`.

Now my main question is: **"Assuming the above design, how should I define the `@ManyToOne` relationships in this design?"**

**NOTE:** I believe if we add an additional `ID` column to the `MovieActor` join-table instead of the composite/embedded `MovieActorId`, the JPA code will become fairly straight-forward. But suppose we have some sort of limitation, and we need to stick to this design as much as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [@MapsId](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) which provides the mapping for an `EmbeddedId` primary key in `@ManyToOne` relation

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class MovieActorId implements Serializable {
    
    private long actorId;
    private long movieId; 

    // constructor, setter, etc
}

@Data
@Entity
public class MovieActor {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private MovieActorId id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId("actorId")
    private Actor actor;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId("movieId")
    private Movie movie;
    ...
}
```